# using python and matplotlib to graph '1.888409001e+002;1.468905193e-002'

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, scientific-notation

I have data within a file that I need to plot. The data pretty much looks like this: `1.988479004e+002;1.498905197e-002`

I have changed the text to: `1.988479004*10**+002;1.498905197*10**-002`.

*Do I need to change the `*10**` to something else for it to function with `matplotlib`? How could I plot this data?*

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking here. Python understands scientific notation. What should the plot look like in the end? Those are just two numbers.

Comment: Can you show the *minimal* code that reproduces your problem and attempts making a plot, then specify what should be different?

Comment: The data that you have, i.e. `1.988479004e+002;1.498905197e-002` is itself enough for Python to understand that it is `(198.8479004, 0.01498905197)`. So you should already be able to plot it without having to change anything